# How to add different Images for Splashscreen

Tags: android, splash-screen

How can I add images of different dimensions for Splash Screen?

I have watched some tutorials concerning this, but they always use a single image. I believe there ought to be several images to fit different screen sizes and density. How do I go about adding these images?

Comment: Splash screens are actually considered a really bad practice in Android development, as they tend to artificially increase the startup time for no reason. Only use a splash screen if there's actual work that needs to be done in the background.

Comment: Why don't you add different images according to your resolutions in the different drawable folders ?

Comment: As @Qrchack said, splash screens are bad in android so instead of that you can use one time intro screen. Like this for reference https://github.com/paolorotolo/AppIntro

Comment: Launch screens aren't explicitly bad and can provide brand exposure.  I would recommend following the material design guidelines on the subject https://material.google.com/patterns/launch-screens.html

Comment: I agree with @JamesMcCracken. Splash screens aren't bad *per se*, but they're becoming an annoyance to users when you add them just to show off your logo. Don't use them unless there's something loading that takes a lot of time. Besides, why would you waste your users' time on watching a logo instead of using your app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use **configuration qualifiers** on your resource folders to indicate when they should be used.  You can simply add the folder to the file structure, or use Android Studio's wizard ( **New -> Android resource directory** ).

[image: resource directory wizard]

These qualifiers can specify size, density, orientation, aspect ratio, etc.  For example:

```
res/layout/my_layout.xml              // layout for normal screen size ("default")
res/layout-large/my_layout.xml        // layout for large screen size
res/layout-xlarge/my_layout.xml       // layout for extra-large screen size
res/layout-xlarge-land/my_layout.xml  // layout for extra-large in landscape orientation

res/drawable-mdpi/graphic.png         // bitmap for medium-density
res/drawable-hdpi/graphic.png         // bitmap for high-density
res/drawable-xhdpi/graphic.png        // bitmap for extra-high-density
res/drawable-xxhdpi/graphic.png       // bitmap for extra-extra-high-density

res/mipmap-mdpi/my_icon.png         // launcher icon for medium-density
res/mipmap-hdpi/my_icon.png         // launcher icon for high-density
res/mipmap-xhdpi/my_icon.png        // launcher icon for extra-high-density
res/mipmap-xxhdpi/my_icon.png       // launcher icon for extra-extra-high-density
res/mipmap-xxxhdpi/my_icon.png      // launcher icon for extra-extra-extra-high-density
```

You can read more about [Supporting Multiple Screens](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) from the documentation.

Comment: So when i want to reference the images, I'd simply use its name once?

Comment: That's right.  Then Android will choose the correct version based on device size, orientation, etc.